# ReactJS Devtools only shows <TopLevel>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a strange issue where my components are rendering properly (server-side) but the **React** tab in chrome devtools is only showing `<TopLevel></TopLevel>`. I've confirmed that `window.React` is available, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Has the answer below solved your particular problem? Mine only differs from the fact that I'm not doing server-side rendering.

Comment: @E_net4 did you ever figure it out? I just posted a similar question.

Comment: Not really, thus why I commented. I am also bundling with browserify and putting React in the global scope (although this isn't required anymore since the latest version would look for `require("react")`). The outcome is still the same as this question's.

Comment: @E_net4 ever figure this out? i'm having the same problem and can't work it out.

Comment: @Liam good thing you bumped this. Have a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229771/making-browserify-bundle-play-nice-with-reactdevtools), I have posted an aswer.

Answer (score 0):

I thing, your components are rendering initially because of server-side rendering.
There must be some problem in bootstrapping on client-side

Comment: Yes, I'm rendering on the server-side.

Comment: I found this [example](https://github.com/zertosh/ssr-demo-kit/tree/master/minimal) useful for setting up react server-side rending and bootstrapping it on client side