# Making Browserify bundle play nice with ReactDevTools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

React 0.13.3

I started using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to organize my frontend React code. I'm also using the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) Chrome extension for debugging. However, I'm having trouble with some very simple React code.

```
var React = require('react/addons');

//React DEV-TOOLS requires React to be on the global scope. Scope is hidden when bundling
window.React = React;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
               <p>Hello world</p> <!-- Renders fine -->
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The following code actually works, and "Hello world" renders fine. The trouble starts when I start the React debugger in my console. I would expect it to say the following:

```
<Top Level>
    <App>...</App>
</Top Level>
```

But instead, it simply says:

```
<Top Level></Top Level>
```

How can `<App>` be rendered without the React devtools recognizing them?

Comment: I am also seeking for a solution to this problem. Even the exposure of `react` at the browserify level might either not trigger the React tab or just show the `Top Level`. What version of React are you using?

Comment: @E_net4, I'm using the latest

Comment: please put the actual version in the question.

Comment: Strange I just took your code using browserify+reactify and it works fine for me

Comment: @Robert should I try using reactify instead? I'm actually just using regular `react-tools` and using watchify on it

Comment: @Carpetfizz yea try that. I also noticed the React tab doesn't show up until you close dev tools and reopen (if it was previously open)

Comment: @Robert Processing the code with browserify+reactify does not make any difference besides possibly different whitespace and semi-colons. In practice, it did not solve the problem on this side either.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you guys... Maybe react tools works for me because I'm running the Linux version of Chrome although I doubt that's it.  Does <Top Level> populate on Facebook's newsfeed?

Comment: @Robert yeah it works on Facebook and Instagram. The problem was actually being caused by a library called `react-google-maps` for me, and the author just pushed an update which made it work!

Comment: After a few more tests, I managed to have that example working properly. So yes, it could be a conflict with other pieces of our own work. Any clues of why this is happening when using particular components?

Comment: I believe one of the other components had a mount error which somehow prevented its parent from appearing in the console.

Comment: Well luckily, I found the source of my own problem as well. It seems to be an issue with the `react-loaders` package in my case. I will file an issue.

Comment: To those wondering, [here's the issue](https://github.com/jonjaques/react-loaders/issues/2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems enough people have stumbled upon this matter, and the [official guide](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools#the-react-tab-doesnt-show-up) does not mention this particular symptom. After gathering enough evidence, it is best that an answer is posted here, even if there might be other causes to this `<Top Level></Top Level>` issue.

The React DevTools may not work if there is more than one instance of React in the bundle. This is often related with an incorrect bundling tool configuration (browserify or webpack) in a particular component. React components (and other libraries supported by React, such as Mixins) should always have `react` as a `peerDependency` in npm and as an "external" in browserify/webpack. This will make it so that a distributable version of the module will not embed React for itself. In addition, if React add-ons are used, "react/addons" may also have to be registered as an external dependency.

In cases where this was not followed, the mere inclusion of the module with `require` (or ES6's `import`) will render the dev tools useless. When another instance of React emerges, that one will register itself as the source of the element tree, which is why an empty element is shown. I have tracked down this bug in `react-loaders` ([issue #2](https://github.com/jonjaques/react-loaders/issues/2)), and it's now fixed since 1.2.3. The same might have happened to [`react-google-maps`](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) according to what @Carpetfizz said, although I have not looked deeply into this case.

One easy trick to debug this is to take a barebones module + web page and iteratively add `require` instructions until the React dev tools stop working. Once the faulty component is found, file an issue.

```
var React = require('react');
var Loader = require('react-loaders'); // testing react-loaders

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
               <p>Check the React tab!</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Another peculiar solution was carried out in the [React packages for Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages), where the development runtime was changed to load the main instance of React last ([commit](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/commit/d252cac49e35e4e911a4e9aa4ada31a5f69da9ac)).

This topic was lifted in issue [#90](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/90), which helped identify more cases of non-compliant packages.

Comment: I can confirm this was causing the issue in my case as well, react-intl was importing a beta version of react 0.14 into my webpack bundle in addition to the 0.13 one. Once I updated its package.json to specify react as a peerDependency and removed react from its node_modules directory, re-webpackaged, the dev tools started working again